# How much is performance degraded when running vertx embedded within jetty or tomcat?

Tags: java, gradle, reverse-proxy, vert.x

How much is performance degraded when running vertx embedded within jetty or tomcat?

Considering running a vert.x based reverse proxy standalone versus embedded, within tomcat or jetty.  High level vert.x documentation discourages embedded vert.x, but I am not clear on what exactly makes it less desirable, other than the obvious additional overhead.

Comment: Will you use the Servlet layer for inbound requests or will you expose an HTTP endpoint with Vert.x (ie Netty), using Jetty/Tomcat as a mere application container?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to embed vertx in jetty or tomcat. Would you embed jetty in tomcat? Or tomcat in JBoss?

Comment: Vert.x is a standalone framework, it provides everything you need to build a complete server application. What do you hope to gain from embedding it inside anything?

Answer (score 0):

There is no significant performance degradation running Vertx inside Jetty or Tomcat, besides general degradation due to multi-tenancy of applications (the contention for server resources and lots of interacting configurations).